# Sending a file over TCP connection

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send i file over TCP but when i try to run this the connection fails, the server receives the file but it gives this error: ERROR: Client timed out before sending a file

```
import selectors
import sys
from socket import *
import sock

sel1 = selectors.DefaultSelector()
print(len(sys.argv), sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

host = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])
file = sys.argv[3]


try:
    # Instaniating socket object
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    # Getting ip_address through host name
    host_address = gethostbyname(host)
    # Connecting through host's ip address and port number using socket object
    s.connect((host_address, port))

    sel1.register(
        sock,
        selectors.EVENT_READ, data = None)
    fileToSend = open("file.txt", "rb")
    data = fileToSend.read(1024)
    while data:
        print("Sending...")
        fileToSend.close()
        s.send(b"Done")
        print("Done Sending")
        print(s.recv(1024))
        s.shutdown(2)
        s.close()



except:
# Returning False in case of an exception
 sys.stderr.write("Connection Failed")
```

Comment: You never send `data` to the server, you only send `Done`.

Comment: Why are you closing the file and socket in the loop? You shouldn't close the socket until you've finished the loop and sent the whole file.

Comment: You need to keep reading the file in the loop.

Comment: My advice is to skip the `try`/`except` until you get things working.  Until that point, you WANT to see the actual exceptions, not your watered down message.

Comment: Thank You! now im undertsanding better the problem is that now it says that done is an unexpected keyword argument

Answer (score 1):

Do the writing in a loop.  There's no particular reason to chop it into 1024-byte pieces; the network stack will handle that for you.

By the way, your "Done" signal is not a good idea, especially since you're writing a binary file that might very well contain the word "Done".  Remember that TCP is a streaming protocol.  The other end does not see the exact packets you're sending.  That is, just because you send 1024 bytes and 4 bytes, the other end might see it as reads of 256 and 772 bytes.

```
# Instaniating socket object
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
# Getting ip_address through host name
host_address = gethostbyname(host)
# Connecting through host's ip address and port number using socket object
s.connect((host_address, port))

fileToSend = open("file.txt", "rb")
print("Sending...")
while True:
    data = fileToSend.read(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    s.send( data )

fileToSend.close()
s.send(b"Done")
print("Done Sending")
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, now the issue is that it says "No data expected until the accio command is issued!",